# Wordpress rewrites not working. Getting 404

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

We are launching a new website and I have to route old urls.

But I cannot get rewrites to work. After two hours of struggling with add_rewrite_rule function I figured I'm too stupid for that, so I decided to use a Rewrite plugin. It looks nice, but my rewrites are still not working.

Is there anything wrong with this rule? Why I'm getting a 404 error?

```
^news.aspx$   ===>   index.php?category_name=news
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with redirect rules in your .htaccess? Here is one example according to the one you gave (don't forget to change http://example.com with your real domain name):

```
Redirect "/news.aspx" "http://example.com/index.php?category_name=news"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your permalinks again: Settings -> Permalink -> Save changes